# What is a normalized Turing Machine

Tags: logic, computer-science, turing-machines

Could you explain to me the difference between a Turing machine and a normalized turing machine?

How does for example a standard operation (e.g., addition, subtraction, multiplication) differ at each case?

Comment: Can you reveal where you're seeing this terminology? It sounds like a word that different authors could be using with quite different meanings.

Comment: I am looking at some german notes, and there it is the notion "normiert" and I thought that in english that is called "normalized". Are you familiar with that german notion? @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 1):

The definition is:

A Turing machine $M$ over alphabet $\{a_1,\dots,a_k \}$ is called *normalized* if its program satisfies the following condition: from every non-final state $q_i$ of $M$ we can only reach states $q_j$, where $j ≤ k (i + 1)$.

This can be achieved by just reordering the states of any Turing Machine by swapping them to change their order. So the normalized machine looks just the same as the original one, you just look at the states in a different order. But since the states are in a set, this order is not really part of the machine; it can, however, be convenient for some proofs.

Arithmetic operations are not really standard operations for TMs. They just move left or right and rewrite the symbol their head is on. Anything more complex is already a program for a TM.

Comment: This is certainly a _reasonable_ use of the word "normalized", but I don't think it is so standard that it can be assumed it is the one that is meant in the OP's (unknown) context.

Comment: Does this mean that a normalized TM is a machine where the tape of the output is the same as the one at the input but it contains also the result?

Comment: This notion of normalized is independent of the details of the TM like: number of tapes, way of accepting/rejecting/producing output etc., because the normalized device is the SAME as the original one. You just suppose an order on the set of states and then change this order to fulfill the conditions of being normalized. But none of this affects the way in which the TM works.

Comment: As Henning has remarked, there might be other notions of "normiert" like for example: "not using space to the left of the input, only to the right"  Different normal forms/normalizations are handy for different types of proofs.

Answer (score -1):

Normalized turing machine means that there exists only 1 accepted state and 1 rejected state.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1221869)